# split an image into tiles efficiently

Tags: android, image, bitmap, split

I am trying to do an application in which an image is being split into many tiles.I followed [this](http://androidattop.blogspot.in/2012/05/splitting-image-into-smaller-chunks-in.html) tutorial,but its not working.FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION error.Some others are also facing the same error who followed this tutorial.The problem is i guess its not memory efficient.Can someone please help me out with this.Can you suggest a tutorial that helps in splitting an image efficiently.I am new to android programming.So please help me out

Comment: The image you are using is too large so the system is throwing failed binder transaction. try it with smaller images first

Comment: @IllegalArgument:thanks a lot :) it did work :) So is it like big images cant be split into small pieces? Is there a way out :)

Comment: Na..thanks.. the code works for my required size :) thanks for the help